# Date in Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make countdown for website. I have simple javascript code as below. Last line in code gives output 5 where it should give output zero as I have not assigned any hour value to it. And as a result my countdown stops 5 hours late then exact time I want it to stop.

```
var date1 = new Date("2019-12-09");
document.write(date1.getHours());
```

Comment: I feel like you're leaving out some important context...

Comment: It's because by default it puts it at midnight UTC, if you don't provide a time yourself. You probably are in a GMT + 5 timezone.

Comment: You can work with UTC methods, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours

Comment: can I simply subtract 5 hours from it get correct time?

Comment: Simply subtracting 5 hours would not suffice, if you have users in different time zones

Comment: how do I get exact time without offset? I want to design countdown for website with users in different time zones.

Comment: to get zero try this: `var date1 = new Date("2019-12-09 UTC");`

Comment: It gives output NOT A NUMBER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getTimezoneOffset()` and then subtract it off:

```
var date1 = new Date("2019-12-09");
console.log(date1.getHours() + date1.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: document.write(date1.getTimezoneOffset()); gives me output as -330 indicating offset. So, to get the correct answer I need to add offset.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll adjust the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you create the `Date` without specifying the timezone, it will treat it as if the hours/minutes/seconds were set to zero and then the whole date was converted to your *local* timezone (timezone of the browser to be specific). Depending on where you are in the world, it can be many hours off the mark. Because of that, every time you need to compare two dates (either for countown or anything else), you have to either use UTC methods or make sure you specify the timezone on *both* dates explicitly:

```
const timeZero = new Date('01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT')    // <<- explicit GMT timezone
const isoTimeZero = new Date('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z') // ISO format of the same
...

const today = new Date();
const utcDateStr = `${today.getUTCFullYear()}-${today.getUTCMonth()+1}-${today.getUTCDate()} 00:00:00.000 GMT`
const utcDate = new Date(utcDateStr)

const offsetInMillisec = utcDate - timeZero   // You can calculate hours/munites left to zero as needed
```

This example ignores hours/minutes/seconds - they are easy to add in the same fashion as the date. The key is to always use the same timezone for both days, preferably UTC

Alternatively, you may want to consider switching to [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and saving yourself lots of hassle :)